# Django debug toolbar not showing view class name

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-debug-toolbar

I am using a django-debug-toolbar==3.4.0 with Django==4.0.5.

Everything works except I see this on the debug toolbar:

[image: django class view name]

The expected string should be the class name: DashboardView not "backend_base.views.view".

Tha class itself is very simple:

```
class DashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin, NavBarMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard.html'
```

In the old version of the same project the result was exactly the classname.
What am I missing?

Comment: by downgrading django to version 3.2 this problem will be solved.

Comment: Can you please point me to docs/sources/commit to understand your answer? Downgrading is not an option in my case. Thanks

Comment: i reported the issue and i hope it will be fixed. https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/issues/1642